# Which version of BeautifulSoup works with GAE (python 2.5)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, beautifulsoup

When I write

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

I am getting the following error:

```
No module named BeautifulSoup
```

All files are saved at project folder, subfolder BeautifulSoup. And it works well if BeautifulSoup.py placed at the same folder where main.py is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to include `BeautifulSoup` from a subpackage (subdirectory), make sure that directory has a `__init__.py` file.

Afterwards `from BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup` should work.